# Call batch from trigger after certain amount of time?

Tags: trigger, batch

I have one trigger on record insert and also one batch is called from the trigger and one field "age" value passed to that batch.

Here now i have requirement is like suppose i have inserted one record with "age" value 25 then i want to call that batch after 2 hours from that trigger.

Comment: Im not sure what your trigger actually does but have you looked into Time Based Workflows?

Comment: Why do you want to stagger the batch process by time?

Comment: What have you actually done to try to achieve this?

Comment: Actually two records are insreted through the data loader utility with different age value so it was called batch program at the same time and facing data locking error. So here i just want to hold that batch for one record for some couple of time so meanwhile first record batch completed.

Comment: You are very much having an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. What are you actually trying to achieve? What error are you running into? Please **[edit]** your question to be more specific about the high level.

Comment: Nothing more completed problem. Just want to know if we can schedule batch to run after 2 hours from the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.schedule()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) to schedule a job to run sometime in the future, and in the `finish` method of that job, cancel the job. This prevents it from running more than once.

You'll need to create a [cron expression](http://www.cronmaker.com/) of the current time, and then add whatever value you need to the hours (instead of the minutes). Pass this expression over to your job, and you'll have a job that you can delay based on whatever conditions you need.

From [Run a scheduled Apex job once](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002809&type=1):

> Example code for running a job 10 minutes from now only once
>
> ```
> String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
> String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute() + 10); 
> String ss = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());
>
> //parse to cron expression
> String nextFireTime = ss + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' * * ?';
>
> MyScheduledJob s = new MyScheduledJob(); 
> System.schedule('Job Started At ' + String.valueOf(Datetime.now()), nextFireTime, s);
> ```
>
> Abort the job by adding a finish method to your class that implements the Schedulable Interface. This stops the job from running more than once.
>
> Example code to abort the job
>
> ```
> global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
> {
> // Get the ID of the AsyncApexJob representing this batch job from Database.BatchableContext.
> // Query the AsyncApexJob object to retrieve the current job's information.
> AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email ..... FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = 
> :BC.getJobId()];
>  //then use the active job id and abort it
>  system.abortJob(a.id);
>  }
> ```

---

In response to your comments:

I'd adjust your batch class to be able to handle records of different ages, since it sounds like your calling multiple batches, which you want to avoid, for exactly that reason.

See if you can figure out how to call a single job to hit all your records. Otherwise, my answer has some code on how to delay jobs.

You could also use the [`Queueable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) interface, these  jobs are meant to be chained, and can call another job when they finish their work. You would pass your ages, perform some actions for the first age, then start another job, and pass along the rest of the ages.